# What are the techniques to protect preventively own software developed in Java etc. against 0days exploit?

Tags: security

I just stumbled upon this article:
Lessons from Anonymous on cyberwar
A cyberwar is brewing, and Anonymous reprisal attacks on HBGary Federal shows how deep the war goes.
http://english.aljazeera.net/indepth/opinion/2011/03/20113981026464808.html

Are there techniques to really protect our own developed software against highly sophisticated techniques ?

For example can't a simple crc check be enough ?

uPDATE: My question is not about protecting the software against cracking, it's about protecting the USER pc from being infiltrated. why wouldn't be enough to just check the crc and avoid running if it is not right ?

Comment: For strong encryption, rot-13 twice instead of once.

Comment: @Heath: Any even number of rot-13 transformations will do :)

Comment: @Heath Hunnicutt: You just made me tear :')

Comment: Another contradiction in this post is asking how to prevent 0 day exploits, that is a logical fallacy. A 0 day exploit by definition is unstoppable because it's not even known to exist, let alone that it even needs fixed.

Comment: Even if you think you've got a secure system or program, there's always another layer to attack. It's turtles all the way down, man...

Answer (score 5):

There is no guaranteed full protection. If you want your software be uncrackable or unexploitable, don't release it at all.

Comment: "don't release it at all." should actually be `don't even write it at all!` Networks get broken into and source code stolen even prerelease like that happened with half life 2 and valve.

Comment: @Chris: well, if it's not released by you, it's not your software any more :)

Comment: @Vlad so when hackers released the source for Half Life 2 before HL2 was released it wasn't Valve's software anymore?

Comment: @Chris: de jure, it was; but in fact, Valve could still do _the right thing_ (from the uncrackability point of view only!) and not release the software!

Comment: @Vlad My question is not about protecting the software against cracking, it's about protecting the USER pc from being infiltrated. why wouldn't be enough to just check the crc and avoid running if it is not right ?

Comment: @user: you cannot, really. There is always a chance of buffer overflow or the like. And what are you going to check with the CRC? Your executable? If the executable is already changed, it's too late, the attacker is already inside.

Answer (score 2):

You want your software to verify checksums?  Of what?

If the highly sophisticated techniques exploit problems in the network, the operating system or hardware; then no, user-ring software doesn't enter the picture so verifying checksums won't help.

If you want to checksum every incoming message, then you need to be able to enumerate all the possible safe incoming messages, in which case you've got an easier to use filter than checksums.

If you want to reject every incoming message that doesn't match a small list of checksums, then you've just turned one kind of attack into another : a denial of availability.  This may be fine for some systems but not most.

Comment: I don't want to checksum the incoming message, I want to checksum my own exe and prevent it from running if checksum not good.

Comment: @user310291, That might be a worthwhile trip-wire to stop a compromised app from gaining privileges implied by user-interaction with a previously safe binary, but if a sophisticated attacker can change your binary, then they might also be able to remove checks or change the checksum.  This also won't stop your binary from being compromised while running.

Answer (score 0):

There is no protection against 0-days,  after all thats the very definition of an 0-day. **ALL software is vulnerable**.

But you can plan on failure.  That is the point behind [Defense in depth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defence_in_depth).
What you can take into mind is the principal of least privilege access.  Security in layers.